# Number Format and angular

Tags: angular

In My Angular 6 app we don't have internationalization or we don't have any mechanism where the user selects any language or region, but I want to do a number format based on their localization if the application is being used in Germany then use that culture, otherwise same for other country and default to 'en-US'

I have set below code to setup a service which will give me locale, but I am not sure how to test it, and is this effective way to do this.

```
@Injectable({
providedIn:'root'
})
export class LocaleService{
  public locale:string;
  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) locale: string) {
    this.locale = locale;
  }
}
```

can anyone provide a more practical and scalable approach?

Answer (score 0):

You just provide a "fake" locale and you test the expected outcome.

```
it("does something in certain way depending on locale",()=>{
   expect(new LocaleService("PL_pl").sayHi()).toEqual("Cześć");
   expect(new LocaleService("En_en").sayHi()).toEqual("Hi");
   expect(new LocaleService("DE").sayHi()).toEqual("Tshus"); // correct me here xD
})
```

Comment: it is not question about just testing, but is this right approach ?

Comment: See Angular I18n

Comment: I already stated I don't use I18n in our app, I just want to check users region/language where the app is being used and do culture-based formatting

Comment: This is how I would do. And probably I would use it as pipe, not service.

Comment: how ? are you missing code ?

Comment: Everything is here, you got the example of public contract. Now just implement it.